# Android WebView cache only images

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Is there any option to cache only images in WebView ? My current settings:

```
wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);        
wv.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);    
wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

But this is caching all requests I need to cache only images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350466/load-webview-cached-image-into-an-imageview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128952/caching-in-android-webview

Comment: wv.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8); wv.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/com.your.package.appname/cache"‌​);